# Any way to use codeigniter to display a system msg consistently?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to have a bar like the stackoverflow bar......
To identificate the user action result, for example, logined success and update success.
So, I have a load function, that allow me to pass the param for me to display, like this:

```
private function _load_register($aData, $aMsg)

{

//the loading method, bababa. 

}
```

And in the view, I have something like this:

```
            <?php if (isset($sys_msg)):?>
                <?php echo($sys_msg);?>
            <?php endif?>
```

But I think it is work, but not so elegant. Because when my script change to ajax script, it can't display. So, I am think of making a manager to do this kind of displaying msg. Any ideas on that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so really what I think the issue is, you can't pass the PHP variable `$sys_msg` in your view to AJAX. I don't see why not, if the javascript is in your view file - why don't you echo out the PHP variables in-line within your javascript code once you pass it to your view. It seems like you may already be doing that, and if your having issues with race conditions and PHP processing before javascript and your using jQuery, you can put in the code after the `$(document).ready(function() {`